# Where is the composition root in a Windows Phone app?

Tags: windows-phone-7, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I'm new to WP 7. For purposes of dependency injection, I want to adhere to practices acquired doing WinForms apps. I therefore want to build my app graph at the composition root. What part of a regular WP 7 app source code can be viewed as the composition root?

Comment: @Claus - DI doesn't require reflection. Funq, for example, uses registered factory delegates to get the job done with little to no performance penalty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pattern I prefer, [as recommended by the Patterns & Practices team](http://wp7guide.codeplex.com/), is:

- Add a `ViewModelLocator` class to your resources `App.xaml` with an `x:Key="ViewModelLocator"`, and add to that class a property for each ViewModel type and lazy-instantiates the VM using the container.
- Configure your dependencies in the application constructor (`App()` in App.xaml.cs) and provide the container instance to the `ViewModelLocator` (via `Application.Resources["ViewModelLocator"]`)
- Bind the ViewModel to each page by assigning `DataContext="{Binding ViewModelPropertyName, Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}}"`

See the [WP7 Guide](http://wp7guide.codeplex.com/) for a working implementation.