# How solve circular reference in Caliburn.Micro

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-8.1, caliburn.micro, circular-dependency

I am working with **Caliburn.Micro** v2.0.1 on a **Windows 8.1 Unversal (WinRT)** project.

I followed the [Caliburn.Micro Working with WinRT](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Working%20with%20WinRT) example.

My code looks as follows:

### App.xaml.cs

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    Initialize();
    DisplayRootViewFor<LoginViewModel>();
}

protected override void PrepareViewFirst(Frame rootFrame)
{
    _container.RegisterNavigationService(rootFrame);
}
```

### LoginViewModel.cs

```
public LoginViewModel(INavigationService navigationService, ...)
{
   ...
}
```

### The issue

The `OnLaunched` is called first.

`Initialize()` Configures the WinRT container.

1. The `DisplayRootViewFor<LoginViewModel>` invokes an instance of  the `LoginViewModel` and results in a Null exception because NavigationService has not yet been registered by `PrepareViewFirst(Frame)`
2. `PrepareViewFirst(Frame)` is not yet called, having a dependency on the `RootFrame` that should be configured by `OnLaunched`

Thus `LoginViewModel` is dependent on `RegisterNavigationService` and `RegisterNavigationService` is dependent on `DisplayRootViewFor<LoginViewModel>()` which is dependent on `LoginViewModel`

Is there any way to overcome this circular reference issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register your services in the container before resolving the `Views` - this way all dependencies are available in the particular Dependency Injection container and you can use `ServiceLocator` to find them.

Typically I've always done this in the `OnStartup()` method of `App.xaml.cs`.

Comment: In the end, `clean` build solved the issue. What you are saying here i'll agree is the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should register/configure your container at the [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/), the earliest access point of your application.

This point depends on what kind of Application you have:

- ASP.NET MVC: Global.asax.cs
- Console Application: the Main Method
- WPF: Application.OnStartup
- WinPhone 7: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/7310492/455493

etc.

Check the Windows 7 lifecycle on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh148153.aspx [image]